# how to open a page in new window using javascript

Tags: php

I want to open a page in new tab as _blank in anchor tag.But window.location will open in same page.

```
   if(isset($_REQUEST['add']))
   {
    function re()
      {
       echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
       window.location='admin_register.php';
       </SCRIPT>"); 
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this using jquery

```
var url = "http://google.com";
$("<a>").attr("href", url).attr("target", "_blank")[0].click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `window.open`

```
 if(isset($_REQUEST['add']))
   {
    function re()
      {
       echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
       window.open('admin_register.php','_blank');
       </SCRIPT>"); 
      }
   }
```

**OR**

```
<a href="#something" onclick="window.open('admin_register.php','_blank');">Click Here</a>
```

**BUTTON ?**

```
<button onclick="window.open('admin_register.php','_blank');">Click here</button>
```

Comment: I want to use button instead of anchor tag

Comment: @saru added button. Your question content doesn't say anything about a button: `"I want to open a page in new tab as _blank in anchor tag"`. However I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved with this code.

```
 <button name="add"  class="admin" onclick="admin()">Add Admin</button>
 script>
 function admin() {
   window.open("admin_register.php");
  }  
 </script>
```